# Django+gunicorn+nginx telegram webhook ssl trouble

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, telegram-bot

I was trying to setup a django as webhooks for telegram bots.
I create a ssl cert's using this commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out webhook_pkey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key webhook_pkey.pem -out webhook_cert.pem
# In Common Name i type a server IP address
```

Setup run gunicorn on port 800, setup proxy_pass in nginx to localhost:800. Web site work correctly, i can open it on browser and see my main page.
Gunicorn starts with that command:

```
gunicorn wsgi -b 127.0.0.1:800
# wsgi is django generated wsgi.py file
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:800;
}
server {
    listen      80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name     111.111.111.111 # these ip addres of my server
    ssl_certificate /path/to/webhook.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/webhook.pkey;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location /media  {
        alias /path/to/media;
    }

    location /static {
    alias /path/to/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:800;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;
    }
}
```

I'm use a pyTelegramBotApi.

```
from telebot import TeleBot
bot = TeleBot(token)
cert = open('webhook.cert', 'r')
bot.remove_webhook()
bot.set_webhook("https://111.111.111.111:80/user_bots/, certificate=cert)
# I'm trying a differents ports
cert.close()
```

`user_bots` - it's some path for view in django, where a logging some data from request
After i run this code i see this in nginx `access.log`:

```
149.154.167.200 - - [26/Oct/2017:15:36:13 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xC3\x01\x00\x00\xBF\x03\x03\x19\xB3\x937v\x14\xF0\xDCj\xC1\x93\xB2?\xF9tOK\x10\x9FA\x87|\xA9!\x81e\xCFC\xDD\x92\x94\x97\x00\x008\xC0,\xC00\x00\x9F\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xCC\xAA\xC0+\xC0/\x00\x9E\xC0$\xC0(\x00k\xC0#\xC0'\x00g\xC0" 400 182 "-" "-"
# And then many some logs, it stopped after i run bot.remove_webhook()
```

Google say it's error with ssl cert.

django `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += url(r'user_bots/(?P<token>[0-9]+:\w*)/.*$', views.bot_test, name="bot_test")
```

`bot_test view`:

```
def bot_test(request, token):
    logging.info(f"Request from bot with token {token}")
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

I need to my django app choose what bot need to doin reference by it token.

I'm stucked :( I trying to resolve that issue all day, maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is very easy :)
Replace

```
cert = open(PATH_TO_CERT, 'r')
bot.set_webhook(url=f'https://111.111.111.111:80/user_bots/{token}/',
                certificate=cert)
```

To

```
bot.set_webhook(url=f'https://111.111.111.111:443/user_bots/{token}/',
                certificate=open(PATH_TO_CERT, 'r')
```

And all work fine!